# Navigate to URL is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, forcenavigatetourl

I have a lightining component code with controller for redirecting the page,while redirecting the page,the url i have posted having parsing error issue

> My tried lightining component code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

     <div>
        <div>
            <lightning:button label="Print" onclick="{!c.navigate}" class="print-hide" />

        </div>
    </div>  
</aura:component>
```

> Controller:

```
({
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {

   var printoption = component.get("v.recordId");
   var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url":'https:domain name'+printoption'/p?retURL=/'+printoption
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
})
```

Error:`'https:domain name'+printoption'/p?retURL=/'+printoption` this url is having parsing error

Answer (score 3):

While setting your event parameter you need to properly concatenate your string(s) and your printoption variable. this is what is causing the parsing error and wont let you save the component controller.

In short, you are missing a + sign.

Comment: i think print option functionality will not work in lightining @glls

Comment: ? not quite sure I follow your comment

Answer (score 0):

As @glls suggested you need to correct url from

```
https:domain name'+printoption'/p?retURL=/'+printoption
```

to

```
https:domain name'+printoption+'/p?retURL=/'+printoption
```